# Android Application that can clear another applications database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a suite of apps and would like a master application that can clear the data of the other applications and reset them back to factory state.

I have investigated online, and many solutions mention that a device should be rooted to be able to do this. But unfortunately, in my case, this is not possible.

Is it possible for an Android application to be able to clear another applications database without running on a rooted device?

Comment: If they have the same `sharedUserId` setting.

Comment: Hi - do you have any further info on this? Like a tutorial?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid

Answer (score 0):

No need to root a phone/tablet. Basically, all you need is to send intent from your master application to any of your other application, which would "ask" to clear a database, and handle those intent, and clear the database obviously. Here's a link to android docs how to do this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)
   (I assume that you're developer of both the master application and the "suite of applications" too.)